# Number of ways of distributing 6 objects to 6 persons

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of ways of distributing 6 objects to 6 persons such that at least one of them does not get anything.

I worked like

Without restriction total ways= $7^6$

Number of cases in which all persons get something=$6!$

Number of cases where at least one person does not get anything=$7^6-6!$

Am I correct?

Also is the probability that at least one person doesn’t get any object equal to $\frac{7^6-6!}{7^6}$?

Comment: Where does the "$7$" in $7^6$ comes from?

Comment: Without restriction, I believe it would be $6^6$ since you have 6 people to give each object (assuming objects and people are unique).

Comment: i think OP means $7^{th}$ way is when a person does not get any object, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> Total number of ways to distribute $6$ objects among $6$ people such that each person gets exactly **one** object is **$6!$**

**Proof:** A particular object has $6$ choices, i.e. $6$ people to select $1$ from. Similarly, every object has $6$ choices, so total ways are $6^6$.
You might have selected a person and calculated choices for him: $6$ for $6$ objects and $1$ when he does not get any object. This gave you $7^6$, which is incorrect.

So, total ways (without restriction) are $6^6$.
And, number of ways when each person gets $1$ object is $6!$, which you got.

So, required number of ways are $$6^6-6!$$ giving you a probability of $$\frac{6^6-6!}{6^6}$$

Comment: Please correct your first sentence.

Comment: @idea-I thought like for each object, I have 6 choices to give to 6 persons and 1 more choice to give nothing to any of 6 persons. So, it was like 7 choices for each object.
Imagine like 6 persons are 6 boxes, and there is 1 another box called "No-one" box
Now, each object has 7 choices to go into a box. So, from here I calculated ways to distribute 6 objects to 6 persons without any restriction.

Comment: @Idea-What Am I overcounting here with $7^6$ term?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig hope i got you this time...Thanks! :-)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig will you also help me explaining OP where exactly is the over-counting taking place?

Comment: There are $6^6$ ways to assign *persons* to the *objects* when the $6$ objects may *each receive one* from $6$ persons with repetitions allowed.  Among these ways, some persons may not be assigned to any objects *because* several objects have been assigned the same person. @user3767495

Comment: @GrahamKemp true, but how do i make OP understand that it is $6^6$ and not $7^6$?

Comment: with his logic, we can also land at $2^6$ by selection of Yes/No for every object by every person...

Comment: $7^6$, counts ways six people can make a choice to take one from seven objects (with the seventh choice a "no" object).  This may leave you with several people *taking the same* object, and some objects *not taken*, but no person will ever have *more than* one object. @user3767495

Comment: @GrahamKemp looks good! And how to deal with $2^6$? i think even that gives same object to many people...

Comment: @GrahamKemp Might look silly, but if so, what exactly is the difference between $7^6$ and $2^6$?

Comment: To explain why there are $6^6$ ways to distribute six objects to six people, I suggest saying that there are six possible recipients for each of the six objects.

Comment: We are choosing recipients, so there are only six choices, not seven.

Comment: that is done, now want to learn difference in $7^6$ and $2^6$

Comment: if people get to choose objects

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I think, in both ways, an object can be selected by multiple people...what else is different?

Comment: You cannot count distributions that way.  Once a person selects an object, nobody else has the option of selecting that object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86175/discussion-between-idea-and-n-f-taussig).